# Marvel: Contest of Champions: Is PVP real?

Tags: marvel-contest-champions

I was playing Marvel: Contest of Champions game. The Game keeps players' win/loss statistics and displays the stats before every fight.

But every player uniformly I fight has the same stats of about 85% to 90% where my win percentage is 89%! I played more than 200 matches and found this very odd.

Am I really fighting real players or they are just bots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I've found, Marvel: Contest of Champions uses an asynchronous PVP system. This means that you are fighting AI using real opponents' characters. You can see this by the simple fact that you can pause the game during a fight and when you unpause, nothing has happened in your absence.

See [this article](http://www.deconstructoroffun.com/2015/12/how-kabams-contest-of-champions-made.html):

> In Contest’s “Versus” mode, you are technically playing other players – but it is really you playing AI using another team’s players.

Comment: I feel disappointed actually :D to realise that I have never played with a real person in that game. Thank you :D

Comment: C'mon... You thought everyone else sucks just like that? lol

Answer (score -1):

from what I can tell it seems to be bots. When I play a vs round it always seems to be against the players "herbgirl" "coldfeet" and "allisonplays"